# ConnectionManager opens PuTTY in separate window

Tags: windows-7, putty

I'm using Connection Manager to open several SSH connections using PuTTY. Connection Manager opens an empty tab and launches PuTTY in a separate window, instead of opening it in the tab.

How do I get it to open in the same tab?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/putty-extreme-makeover-using-putty-connection-manager/)

> If the PuTTY Connection Manager opens the original PuTTY in a separate
>   window, instead of opening as a TAB, please go to Tools -> Options ->
>   Select the check-box “Enable additional timing for PuTTY capture (ms)”
>   -> set the value to 500 ms. This will open the PuTTY window inside the
>   TAB as shown below.

Comment: Had to follow user223562 advice. Really stupid the ok button not saving the option.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 and the timing capture setting did not fix it for me.  Instead I had to right click on puttycm.exe, select properties, and choose Windows Vista compatibility mode.

Answer (score 6):

I still faced this issue, and found a very stupid fix, once you change the capture ms as mentioned above, there are 2 buttons , 1st that says "OK" and the other one says "Apply", hit "Apply" and then click on "Ok".

I fail to understand why clicking directly on "OK" button didn't save that setting.

Answer (score 3):

Go to *Tools » Options » Plugin » Putty* and enable capture, set time value above 100ms

> Note: this option is designed for people experiencing problems with PuTTY instances hosting. Most common problem is PuTTY process is not attached correctly to PuTTYCM and stays in taskbar while an empty tab is created. If you do not experience any trouble when opening connections then leave this option disabled.